# Highcharts Org chart: Overlapping children in hanging layout

Tags: highcharts

I want to create a simple org chart. It starts with 2 "normal" levels, below I want to use 2 "hanging" levels. Nothing fancy, should work out of the box. But with highcharts the 2 hanging layout are overlapping as you can see in the fiddles.

Org chart with 1 level of hanging layout:
https://jsfiddle.net/rta6nmq4/

```
layout:'hanging'
```

What I want to create is the same chart with 2 levels of hanging layout:
https://jsfiddle.net/rta6nmq4/1/

```
layout:'hanging'
```

Would be super nice if someone can show me how to tackle this issue.

Comment: Note: It seems that the org chart is not able to handle the positioning of mutliple hanging layouts. Badly there is no way to manually set the node position, offset is no option in inverted charts.

Comment: Could you provide an image of the output that you want to achieve? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwdy7m9g/

Comment: Sure, you can check this ticket on github i opened yesterday: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15527

Comment: I could calculate the vertical node positions, but highcharts does not allow to set it :(

Comment: I think that this thread can be continued with the core developers on the Github issue channel